# Javascript try...catch - 2 identical calls, only one works

Tags: javascript

I'm in the process of redesigning a menu/submenu - just moving the submenu from somewhere in the bottom of the page to under its corresponding menu item. Right now, the same submenu (actions) is found twice in page, only that one of the times it's hidden and displayed with jQuery on mouse over. In both menus I have an option pointing to a function with a try...catch block.

Here's the problem, when using the jQuery-displayed actions, Javascript crashes in the try block ("something" is undefined - classical), just like the word 'try' wasn't even there. I've used the firebug debugger, and the same error occurs when using the other submenu, but that was just skipped and the code from inside catch was executed.

I just don't understand how this is possible, given that both options call THE SAME function, not 2 "identical" ones...

Any thoughts? Thanks :)

**EDIT I:**

```
function export_pdf() {
            try {
                ReportType=document.forms["down"].elements["ReportType"].value;
            }
            catch (e) {
                ReportType='TDR_Report';
            }

            //other code...
}
```

And the error is "document.forms.down.elements.ReportType is undefined"...

Thanks!

**EDIT II:**

Calling the function:

```
onclick="export_pdf();"
```

Comment: To edit your post, click the **`edit`** button below the javascript tag, enter the revision, and click the **`Save Edits`** button when done.

Comment: Can you show how you call this function?

Answer (score 0):

In this case, I would simply try to avoid the try .. catch and test the ReportType. If the ReportType is undefined, set the value manually.

```
function export_pdf() {

    if (document.forms["down"].elements["ReportType"] === undefined){
        ReportType = 'TDR_Report';
    } else {
        ReportType = document.forms["down"].elements["ReportType"].value;
    }

    //other code...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I've tried this. Doesn't crash anymore... at least, not in this function. I think I'll just let this idea go until the new design - too much time spent on something so little. Thanks again :)

Comment: In javascript I always tried to get around try..catch, I always tried to prevent exceptions before they could pop up. The try..catch never seemed to work as reliable as it should..